# how to serve xml file as a static content in nginx

Tags: html, nginx, web, static-files

I have a `test.xml` file stored in the location
`/deploy/projects/backend/assets`. I tried to serve this file as a static content when someone accesses this using link `https://xyz/assets/test.xml`. However, it gives error `"404 Not Found"`. My **nginx config file** is as below:

```sh
cat nginx/server.conf
```

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
        
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        
        location ~ ^/assets/ {
            root    /deploy/projects/backend;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are testing an `https` link but you show the configuration of an `http` site. Also, please include the relevant  entries from the Nginx access log and the Nginx error log.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but if change the `root    /deploy/projects/backend;` line to `root    /deploy/projects/backend/assets;` it might work.